# how to highlight selected text/string in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, text

I have a string '**Expert Sales Manager**' as a cell title and i want to highlight only the '**sales**' in the cell title in iphone.
Please suggest me a way for doing so.

Comment: Do you want add **Bold** attribute to **sales**?

Comment: yes i want Bold attribute to sales (only).

Comment: So, you can use Attributed string instead of `NSString` and find the range of **sales** character. OR you can type **Expert Sales Manager** as **Expert <b>Sales</b> Manager** in Attributed string. Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
NSString *infoString=@"This is an example of Attributed String";
NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:infoString];
NSInteger _stringLength=[infoString length];

UIColor *_black=[UIColor blackColor];
UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:30.0f];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_black range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSMutableAttributedString` for ios 6 or later version.

```
   NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"OneTwoThreeFour"];
    [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20] range:NSMakeRange(3,5)];
```

And set your attributed text to your element..

```
label.attributedText = string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **iOS 6**, UIKit supports drawing attributed strings

From `UILabel`:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText;
```

You just need to build up your `NSAttributedString`. There are basically two ways:

1. Append chunks of text with the same attributes - for each part create one `NSAttributedString` instance and append them to one `NSMutableAttributedString`
2. Create attributed text from plain string and then add attributed for given ranges – find the range of your number (or whatever) and apply different highlighting attribute on that.